# Jest - localeForage.createInstance is not a function

Tags: javascript, jestjs, mocking

I am using `localforage` in an application, and I am exporting it, as part of a ContextProvider. The `driver` it uses is IndexDB. The problem is one component is using that Context and when I write tests for it, it needs to access that Context. And I get the following error:

```
TypeError: localForage.createInstance is not a function
    > 4 | const featureContextStore = localForage.createInstance({
        |                                        ^
      5 |   driver: localForage.INDEXEDDB,
```

Any idea how to solve it? I tried, `spyOn`, `mock`, `defineDriver` from `localeForage` itself. Nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 1):

Just add this on top of your test file for all loaclforage functions mock

```
jest.mock('localforage', () => ({
  localforage: {
    createInstance: jest.fn(),
    getItem: jest.fn(),
    setItem: jest.fn(),
    config: jest.fn()
  }
}));
```